# BigQuery query taking >15 minutes

Tags: google-bigquery

I haven't come across a query that takes more than a minute or so in BigQuery, except this one for some reason. Can anyone shed light on why this query would take so long?

If any Google engineers are viewing this, the job ID is job_qHSgmV1CKbJnQeEZpqw1cb1g6f4.

```
SELECT
  DATE(s.signdatetime) fts_date,
  s.passportid,
  s.lifetime_tracking_source,
  SUM(if (MONTH(o.optindatetime)=MONTH(s.signdatetime),o.cpl,NULL)) rev_first_month
FROM
  tableau.signatures s
LEFT JOIN EACH tableau.optins o
ON
  s.passportid=o.passportid
WHERE
  DATE(s.signdatetime) BETWEEN '2015-10-12'
  AND '2015-10-13'
  AND s.disposition="accepted"
  AND s.FTS="Y"
  AND o.finalstatus="collected"
  AND DATE(o.optindatetime) BETWEEN '2015-10-12'
  AND '2015-10-13'
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How big are the tables? I'll suggest filtering data out before doing the join:

```
SELECT
  DATE(s.signdatetime) fts_date,
  s.passportid,
  s.lifetime_tracking_source,
  SUM(if (MONTH(o.optindatetime)=MONTH(s.signdatetime),o.cpl,NULL)) rev_first_month
FROM (
  SELECT signdatetime, passportid, lifetime_tracking_source,
  FROM tableau.signatures 
  WHERE DATE(signdatetime) BETWEEN '2015-10-12' AND '2015-10-13'
  AND disposition="accepted"
  AND FTS="Y"
) s
LEFT JOIN EACH (
  SELECT cpl, optindatetime, passportid
  FROM tableau.optins 
  WHERE finalstatus="collected"
  AND DATE(optindatetime) BETWEEN '2015-10-12' AND '2015-10-13'
) o
ON
  s.passportid=o.passportid
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3
```

Also try GROUP EACH instead of just GROUP.

Comment: Both of those tables are about 30 GB. One with 244,549,729 records, the other with 151,668,971 records. Thank you for the suggestion, I'm going to try that right now.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: The query takes 8.3 seconds now!

Comment: I'll post this as a bigquery tip :)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa -- Where do you post those tips?

Comment: Also -- That's a great solution, but it seems like something that could/should be handled by the query optimizer. Is that kind of deep optimization on the BQ roadmap somewhere?

Comment: Would you like to bet?